# ffmpeg get value from cropdetect

Tags: php, ffmpeg

Its possible to run cropdetect and crop in one line and get thumbs from video?

*something like this*

```
ffmpeg -ss 1 -i 0.flv -vf cropdetect=24:16:0,crop=w:h:x:y -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 240x180 0.jpg
```

Or maybe need to run in 2 line, first run cropdetect and than run crop and generate thumbs from video, but in this way i need to get value from cropdetect?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[`cropdetect`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#cropdetect) outputs to the console, so you can parse the output and then use it as a variable:

```
ffmpeg -i input -t 1 -vf cropdetect -f null - 2>&1 | awk '/crop/ { print $NF }' | tail -1
```

This will result in something like:

```
crop=640:480:0:50
```

Then run your actual crop command:

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf $cropvalue,scale=240:-1 -vframes 1 -qscale:v 2 output.jpg
```

- `-vcodec mjpeg`, `-an`, and  `-f rawvideo` are superfluous
- Use `-qscale:v` to control jpg output quality. A sane range is 2-5 (a lower value is a higher quality).
- Use the [`scale`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) filter instead of `-s`; especially if you're already using filters. Also the `scale` filter will allow you to set a specific width or height and with `-1` it will automatically provide the correct value to preserve aspect. Otherwise if you try to force a specific size you can risk a squished or stretched output.

Obviously I'm not a PHP coder, but this should give you an idea at least.

Comment: Hmm cant get crop value in $cropvalue ... im run in php this code, but when im run in comand line im get value

Comment: Im just create function like this

`function crop($id){
$d = shell_exec("ffmpeg -i $id -t 1 -vframes 1 -ss 50 -vf  cropdetect -f null - 2>&1 | awk '/crop/ { return $NF }' | tail -1");
$array = explode('crop=',$d);
$cropvalue = $array[1];
$cropvalue = 'crop='.$cropvalue;
return $cropvalue;
}`

and than im call in new line 'crop("111.mp4")'

Comment: I would be more rigorous in your cropdetect, this seeks 10 minutes into a movie, and analyzes the film for 2 minutes.. sorts the resulting values then uses uniq, so the most 'popular' value is used.

`ffmpeg -ss 600 -i $filename -f matroska -t 120 -an -vf cropdetect=24:16:0 -y -crf 51 -preset ultrafast /dev/null 2>&1 | grep -o crop=.* | sort -bh | uniq -c | sort -bh | tail -n1 | grep -o crop=.*`

Comment: I know it's a bit late, but you were using `$array = explore('crop=', $d); $cropvalue = $array[1];` on your output. When you explode the output at this value, you would have to use `$cropvalue = $array[0];` since arrays start at 0 in PHP. The output of your shell_exec command would be something like `crop=1440:1072:240:4` or similar. So, you don't need your explode part and concatenate string. Just use the output of shell_exec, so `return shell_exec('...');`.

Comment: @MichaelArmbruster If you mention his name like this then he will be notified of your comment (if he ever logs in again).

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Thanks, that's a great function I did not know of before :)

Comment: What does `-vframes 1` do here? Is it used only because the input/output is a JPEG?

Comment: @HashimAziz `-vframes 1` limits the output to 1 frame, and in the case of outputting a single image avoids the error: `Could not get frame filename number 2 from pattern 'output.jpg' (either set updatefirst or use a pattern like %03d within the filename pattern)`. It is used because in the original question wanted to output a single JPEG image. If you want to output a video then remove `-vframes 1`.

Comment: Brilliant, that's what I suspected. Just to note that the included `cropdetect` filter failed for me because the first second or so of my test video was black with a small logo in the corner and that's all that was cropped. Kevin's solution printed nothing at all. I got yours to work in the end by running the filter after skipping the first few seconds: `ffmpeg -ss 5 -i "Awwal Ma Dakhalna.mp4" -t 1 -vf cropdetect -f null - 2>&1 | awk '/crop/ { print $NF }' | tail -1`.

Comment: Save yourself a bash fork and get `awk` to only print the last matching field. `awk '/crop=/ {a=$NF} END{print a}'`

Comment: this line does NOTHING, where is the file name?