# Python - How to trim black boarder from video (top, bottom, sides)

Tags: python, ffmpeg, moviepy

If I have a `.mp4` video file with black boarders on the top, bottom, and/or sides, How can I trim these boarders off with python?

I do not want to replace the boarders with anything, I just want to trim the video.

For example, if I run `magically_trim_black_boarders_from_vid(in_vid)` on a video that looks like the frame below, the video's height would not change, but its width would be reduced.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We my use [cropdetect](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#cropdetect) filter as described in the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17266356/4926757).

Within Python we may execute FFmpeg as subprocess twice - first time with `cropdetect` filter for finding the black borders, and second time for cropping the borders.

The output of `cropdetect` filter is as a lines of text, that should be parsed:

```
#[Parsed_cropdetect_0 @ 00000232c2705e00] x1:69 x2:551 y1:0 y2:309 w:480 h:304 x:72 y:4 pts:512 t:0.040000 crop=480:304:72:4
#[Parsed_cropdetect_0 @ 00000232c2705e00] x1:69 x2:551 y1:0 y2:309 w:480 h:304 x:72 y:4 pts:1024 t:0.080000 crop=480:304:72:4
...
```

---

Suggested stages:

- Execute FFmpeg as subprocess with `cropdetect` filter, and storing the (`stderr`) output in `cropdetect_output` string:

  ```
   cropdetect_output = sp.run(['ffmpeg', '-hide_banner', '-i', in_video_file, '-vf', 'cropdetect=skip=0', '-t', '1', '-f', 'null', 'pipe:'], stderr=sp.PIPE, universal_newlines=True).stderr
  ```
- Find the substring, that starts with "crop=" and ends by new line using [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) regular expression searching:

  ```
   crop_str = re.search('crop=.*', cropdetect_output).group(0)  # crop=480:304:72:4
  ```
- Execute FFmpeg using [crop](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop) filter with the `crop=` arguments found above.

  ```
   sp.run(['ffmpeg', '-hide_banner', '-i', in_video_file, '-vf', crop_str+',setsar=1', out_video_file])
  ```

---

Code sample:

```
import subprocess as sp
import re

in_video_file = 'wnkaa.mp4'
out_video_file = 'cropped_wnkaa.mp4'

# ffmpeg -hide_banner -i wnkaa.mp4 -vf cropdetect=skip=0 -t 1 -f null
cropdetect_output = sp.run(['ffmpeg', '-hide_banner', '-i', in_video_file, '-vf', 'cropdetect=skip=0', '-t', '1', '-f', 'null', 'pipe:'], stderr=sp.PIPE, universal_newlines=True).stderr

# Return: crop=480:304:72:4
crop_str = re.search('crop=.*', cropdetect_output).group(0)  # Find the first match of "crop=", and return all characters from "crop=" up to new line.

# ffmpeg -hide_banner -i wnkaa.mp4 -vf crop=480:304:72:4,setsar=1 cropped_wnkaa.mp4
sp.run(['ffmpeg', '-hide_banner', '-i', in_video_file, '-vf', crop_str+',setsar=1', out_video_file])
```

Note:
The above command uses default codec arguments (it's just an example).
We may add encoding arguments like `'-vcodec', 'libx264', '-crf', '20', '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p'`...

---

Sample output frame:
[image]